# Can't install openoffice: package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: 11.04, openoffice.org

I dont remember what happened to my OOo but when i wanted to reinstall it i got an error!

[image]

Can someone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing your Unity bar on the left, you're using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty. OpenOffice.org has been replaced by [LibreOffice](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libreoffice).

See also: [What is the difference between OpenOffice and the newly created LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/q/6706/6969)

Comment: ow really, oops thanks ill try downloading that