# What is the difference between libre office and open office ? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

Tags: software-recommendation, libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between OpenOffice and the newly created LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6706/what-is-the-difference-between-openoffice-and-the-newly-created-libreoffice)

I am using **openoffice** before installing ubuntu
but **libreoffice** is default in Ubuntu
What is the difference between **libreoffice** and **openoffice** ? What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?