# Install OpenOffice for headless use

Tags: openoffice.org, headless

The question very simple and short. I am following [this article](http://www.openvpms.org/documentation/install-openoffice-headless-service-ubuntu) to install OpenOffice headless:

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-headless openoffice.org-writer openoffice.org-draw
```

And I get the following error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openoffice.org-headless
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'openoffice.org-headless'
```

**UPDATE:**

```
apt-cache search openoffice.org
```

output: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/1262902/

Comment: what is the output of `apt-cache search openoffice.org`

Comment: Output is pretty huge. What should I find from there ? or should I paste it here ?

Comment: so `sudo apt-get update` then try installing adain

Comment: THat does not helps, please check the output

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Install OpenOffice following [the instruction given at their Website](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-deb).

The installation procedure is as follows:

1. First [Download the openOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org/download/) all in one tar package. You should select Your OS (For me **Linux 64-bit (x86-64) DEB**), Language and Version. Then click on **Download full installation** button to get a `.tar.gz` file
2. Then extract the `.tar.gz` file into a suitable directory. I downloaded in my home directory. You can extract it using a command like this (replace the file name with the exact name you downloaded)

   ```
   tar xf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.2_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
   ```
3. Then open a terminal and go the the directory containing the .deb files. If you extracted in Home directory, the command is

   ```
   cd ~/en-US/DEBS/
   ```
4. Then install all the .deb files with the command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
5. Since, [OpenOffice 2.3 it can be started in headless mode](http://community.nuxeo.com/5.3/books/nuxeo-book/html/admin-openoffice.html). So, you can start it in headless mode with the command

   ```
   soffice --headless
   ```

Hope this will help.

<sup>Tested again in 16.04. It works as before</sup>

Comment: error: The program 'soffice' is currently not installed.....

Comment: @user983803 I again tested this on a server with the instruction. `soffice` is found perfectly in place. Check if you downloaded correct versions and try again

Answer (score 17):

Ubuntu switched to libreoffice instead of openoffice quite a while ago.

Install `libreoffice-common`, then you can run the libreoffice service by adding the "--headless" runtime argument.

```
$ /usr/bin/libreoffice --headless
```

The rest of that article should be compatible if you replace "openoffice.org" with "libreoffice" across the board.

Comment: I am intended to use openoffice for batch conversion by the use of [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter) . So could you provide possible solution to install openoffice ?

Comment: You can use the upstream packages (OpenOffice.org/download). Most distributions no longer offer it.

Comment: Eric is right, LibreOffice has replaced OpenOffice. It's just a fork of the same program, but without licensing restrictions.

Comment: According to its github page, PyODConverter supports both LibreOffice and OpenOffice. https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter

Comment: @Sepero [That's not the difference.](http://askubuntu.com/q/6706/22949) (Or, rather, the way you've put it is misleading, because OpenOffice.org's licensing restrictions weren't against users, or people creating derivative works. The closest thing to heavier licensing restrictions in OpenOffice.org was that developers who wished their code to be merged into OpenOffice.org itself had to assign copyright to Oracle...much like community members who wish their code to be merged into Unity must assign copyright to Canonical.)

Comment: @EliahKagan That's olde. Contributors retain copyright nowadays: http://www.canonical.com/contributors

Comment: I have only LibreOffice (not OpenOffice) installed on my machine and I can run commands with soffice --headless .

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have first completely removed LibreOffice, then follow [Olive Twist's installation instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/197687/22949) and that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Download open office headless from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/openoffice.org-headless)

Although it is the Hardy package, but it should work for you

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice.org Headless install:

```
apt-get install openoffice.org-core
```