# How can I install OpenOffice?

Tags: 13.04, openoffice.org

Hi I'm new to Ubuntu having finally given up the ghost with Windows 8!
On Ubuntu 13.04, I've used the Software Centre to install a number of apps including Skype. However OpenOffice is proving very tiresome.

This is the download:

```
Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

It won't install from the Software Centre, or from double click. Right click doesn't offer an install option.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question seems to be similar to [this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/116590/58950). If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why. On the other hand, why not give LibreOffice (installed by default) a try?

Comment: Why not try libre office? It's based on Open office and installed by default.

Answer (score 8):

Well first thing to do is remove Libreoffice if its installed.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then to install OpenOffice you do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/openoffice 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install apache-openoffice
```

I just tested it on 13.04, and it works.

For Ubuntu 14.04 and above download either the 32bit or 64bit of Apache OpenOffice.

For 32 Bit:

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.3/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.3_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
tar xzf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.3_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

For 64 Bit:

```
wget http://netassist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openofficeorg.mirror/4.1.3/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.3_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
tar xzf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.3_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
```

once extracted, navigate to the DEBS folder where the file was extracted, and issue the command(s) below:

```
cd en-US/DEBS/
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Then  navigate to the desktop-integration folder, and issue the command(s) below:

```
cd desktop-integration/
sudo dpkg -i openoffice4.0-debian-menus*.deb
```

<sup>Source for OpenOffice Install:[Upubuntu](http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/01/install-apache-openoffice-341-from-ppa.html)</sup>

Comment: Cheers - worked a treat

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/openoffice/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich The above PPA will not work for 13.10.  To install for 13.10 see [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-openoffice-4-0-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-debian/).

Comment: `ppa:upubuntu-com/openoffice` seems broken (at least for Ubuntu Trusty).

Comment: @Hibou57 Take a look at the second duplicate answer, or [here](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-openoffice-4-1-1-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-ubuntu-12-04-debian-8-debian-7-and-derivatives/)

Comment: @Mitch, yes, I know, just that I feel it's better to use a PPA when available, as it provides automatic updates. That's why I was disappointed about this.

Comment: If you can't use `add-apt-repository`, see [here](http://lifeonubuntu.com/ubuntu-missing-add-apt-repository-command/).

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/office/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/openoffice/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: @KiranReddy What Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: @Mitch it's 14.04

Comment: This PPA appears to be dead.

Comment: @Cerin Which version of Ubuntu version are you trying to install office on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. And yes, I know it doesn't support 16, which was my point. It looks like compiling from source is the only way to install Openoffice now on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Cerin It says that in the answer.  The PPA is not for 14.04 and above.

Answer (score 0):

or you can install "Libre Office" which is totally identical with the former OpenOffice which declared as a fork to that project by Oracle. More info is at : [Difference between LibreOffice and OpenOffice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6706/what-is-the-difference-between-openoffice-and-the-newly-created-libreoffice)

use Terminal and write :

1- if you already found it in Ubuntu and wand to have the latest version :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

2- OR if you didn't have it installed just write :

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: The OP asked for OpenOffice, not LibreOffice.

Comment: I'm using Libreoffice 5...and it's terrible. Calc crashes, the text doesn't update, and formulas don't refresh.