# Why OpenOffice is not available in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I was wondering, why is it that OpenOffice is not available in Ubuntu.Even if Ubuntu choose LibreOffice over OpenOffice, that does not mean that OpenOffice should be removed or not available as an option. Isn't having options is one of the great things about Linux.

Beside having problems coexisting with LibreOffice, a warning or a statement should be issued when installing OpenOffice from the Software Center, such as 'You can't install OpenOffice and LibreOffice at the same time, please remove LibreOffice'.

Comment: Well, if you want to remove Libreoffice, and install OpeOffice, then look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/298781/how-can-i-install-openoffice/298795#298795).  On a personal note, I tried both, and I use Libreoffice.

Comment: Close-voters: I do not believe this question is primarily opinion-based (or even asking for opinions at all). My understanding is that the switch from OO to LO was made after discussion and for specifically articulated reasons. I suspect there may be some older question (from shortly after the switch) to which this could duped, though. Also, please note that the answer is likely related to concerns about the direction Oracle might have taken OpenOffice.org; after all, they were developing it for a significant time between their acquisition of Sun and when Apache took OO over.