# how do I fix the menu items displayed when using OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice.org, menu-bar

I wanna ask about Ubuntu 12.04 LTS running on my laptop. When I run OpenOffice, the menubar is showing `___` signs, including `File`, `View`, `Edit`, `Tools` etc. then I cannot find the words on it.

[image]

Here's how I installed OpenOffice:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/office
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openoffice
```

Please help me fix this.

I already tried to install OpenOffice just like mitch said and the package won't able to be installed. Then I tried to install LibreOffice 4 [link] ([How can I install OpenOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298781/how-can-i-install-openoffice?rq=1)) and it shows me the problems AGAIN.

Comment: I'm sorry, here the link
http://i.imgbox.com/acp0Qstx.jpg

Comment: What version of OpenOffice are you running? And how did you install it exactly? Please **edit** your question to incorporate more information.

Comment: OpenOffice 3.4
I run it on terminal via ppa

Comment: Again, please *edit* your question to provide all new information. And please be specific which PPA you used. (I've rolled back your earlier edit which rendered the screenshot useless - just don't touch that part - only *add* information.)

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm newbie here. I'l try to edit it

Comment: Please note that the PPA you used hasn't been updated for a long time! https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/office shows the last update is more than a year ago. Consider using the updated https://launchpad.net/~upubuntu-com/+archive/openoffice PPA (note the office changed to openoffice) Also: any reason for running OpenOffice over LibreOffice?

Comment: May I recommend you to try LibreOffice instead, it was forked long ago just when OpenOffice was acquired by Oracle or a bit before. Updates are pushed frequently and it is the new "default" FOSS office package.

Comment: Oh man, Since I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 LibreOffice showed me the same problem. Then I install OpenOffice to do my work here but nothing solved.

Comment: should I add the PPA you gave me there?

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: please help me fix the problems, I cannot do my work right now until the program solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem : First, I realized after all it wasn't about the broken package or configuration itself. Then I tried to run **Ubuntu Tweak** > **Tweak** > **Font**. I changed the default font from **Ubuntu** to **Aurulent Sans Bold Italic** this is the [figure](http://i.imgbox.com/abld3opk.png). So the LibreOffice 4 will show up like [this](http://i.imgbox.com/abqSuqxG.png). Thanks to all user for helping me fix the problems :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is to remove you current openoffice installation.

To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get purge openoffice
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Also you may want to remove the PPA you added.  To do that just: (Thanks to amc)

```
sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:upubuntu-com/office
sudo apt-get update
```

Then download openoffice 3.4.1 from their [website](http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html), and choose you right architecture (Linux Intel DEB or Linux x86-64 DEB).  Once downloaded, from terminal navigate to the download location (probably the Downloads folder), and run the commands below:

```
tar -vxzf Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
cd en-US/DEBS
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
cd desktop-integration
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

wait for the fist command to finish before running the last two commands.

On a personal note, I would go with Libreoffice as Wolter Hellmund recommended.

Comment: You should also remove the ppa before installing from the downloaded deb.

Comment: but LibreOffice shows me the same problem. Should I remove it too ?
Thanks man

Comment: The terminal won't install the package, it shows Errors were encountered while processing:<package_name>.deb
What should I do now?

Comment: You should remove Libreoffice.  Which openoffice file did you download?

Comment: I downloaded intel deb. So what now?
I'm so confued

Comment: I tried with terminal which mention here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/298781/how-can-i-install-openoffice?rq=1 and it shows me the same problem AGAIN.

Comment: I removed openoffice then installed LibreOffice 4 and it shows me the same problem on LibreOffice 4. what's happening here?

Comment: Finally I installed WPS Kingsoft to solve problems. I'm so confused to fix the problems on menubar LibreOffice and OpenOffice.

Comment: What is the name of the file that you downloaded so I can try it?

Comment: which one? WPS or OpenOffice?

Comment: it's Apache_OpenOffice_incubating_3.4.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz

Comment: Look at the extra steps that I've added to my answer, and see if it works.

Comment: Do the problems come from my laptop? or maybe the configuration I didn't understand? But guys, When I ran 11.10 n my laptop, there was nothing wrong.

Comment: Bro, it works. Totally works. I mean It can be installed and be opened but the same problems show again.

Comment: so how can I install package that I already downloaded? I'm so confused because it contains a lot of .deb files

Comment: That's OK, just run the commands and it will install.  Which Java version do you have? run `java -version` in terminal, and let me know.

Comment: it's java version "1.7.0_25"

Comment: But @Mitch , first thing I should do is to extract the .tar.gz file right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Mitch I tried it and it shows me like this : Unpacking ooobasis3.4-base (from ooobasis3.4-base_3.4.1-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ooobasis3.4-base:
 ooobasis3.4-base depends on ooobasis3.4-core01; however:
  Package ooobasis3.4-core01 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing ooobasis3.4-base (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ooobasis3.4-base

Comment: Make sure that you remove any previous installation form Openffice and Libreoffice, and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before trying again.

Comment: @Mitch when I run apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade it shows me like this E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: Make sure no other apps like software center, or synaptic open, and try again.  Need to use `sudo` with both commands.

Comment: it's still error just like that message I showed you @Mitch

Comment: It's error when I install one of the packages