# how to install openoffice 4.1 on ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, openoffice.org

http://sourcedigit.com/12463-install-apache-openoffice-4-1-1-ubuntu-14-04/

i followed the directions posted on this site in their entirety for use with a 64 bit OS and the install appears to have worked except i cannot find the program in software center, and when i open dash and select the main open office icon it will begin loading and then stop. i am in need of working step by step terminal commands to install openoffice 4.1 for ubuntu 12.04 as this is how i managed the same install on my last ubuntu 12.04 64 bit computer and i'm not sure why i'm having difficulty this time around.

tried downloading from a different souce with same result.

Answer (score 0):

With that article, you probably have a few issues - first you are downloading the 32bit version, so the [64bit version](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openofficeorg.mirror/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz) may suit you better. Secondly you may want to download a different locale if you don't use `en_GB` (the UK's one), you can get various versions from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/

This site already has a question on [How to install OpenOffice](https://askubuntu.com/q/116590/178596) - this uses PPA's so may work better (though with a second look it does seem to be outdated). It also should have a version more suitable for the specific distribution of Ubuntu you are using (with dependencies).

Note that Libreoffice, which is included in Ubuntu and other linux systems by default, is more up-to-date and is under a open license: [Why is LibreOffice default instead of OpenOffice.org](https://askubuntu.com/q/315224/178596)

Comment: it has instructions for both system architecture, however even with the 64 bit install on that site it still wouldn't work but i'll definitely check out the sourceforge link you posted.

Comment: also just realized after successful install that ubuntu's ppa is for 3.4 not 4.1 and needs updated just like gimp 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get remove --purge libreoffice* openoffice*
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
wget http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/openofficeorg.mirror/4.1.1/binaries/en-US/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-US.tar.gz
cd en-US/DEBS
dpkg -i *.deb
cd desktop-integration
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: will (apt-get dist-upgrade) upgrade me to ubuntu 14? if so i do not want that. my pc doesnt yet have the graphics to handle running it.