# Opening Macintosh Pages files in Ubuntu

Tags: macosx

I am switching from Macintosh. I want to know if there is an easy way to bulk convert files created by the word processor Pages into something Ubuntu can run. Open Office for example.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There don't appear to be a lot of Pages to OpenDocument Text converters, but luckily there are lots of Pages to Word Document converters, and LibreOffice can read Word documents. I suggest using this website here: https://cloudconvert.com/pages-to-docx.

It allows you to upload multiple documents securely and convert them to a Word document which LibreOffice can read. Later, you can convert them to OpenDocument Text inside of LibreOffice if you wish.

Be warned that if your documents have lots of complex formatting then this may get lost when converting between files.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to convert the documents in Pages, if possible, to a more widely readable formats:

- OpenDocument Format (.odt) so they can be opened in Libre/OpenOffice - [may not be supported](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202227)
- XML Office etc (.doc/.docx) - this can be imported into Libreoffice and in MS office . If can't do ODF probably the next best thing.
- PDF -  should mean that all the formatting etc is presevered, but it is

If you don't currently have access to pages, there are various file converters available (e.g. [ZamZar](http://www.zamzar.com/)) that may work. The problem here is that it is likely to be a proprietary file format, so it probably is not open-able in other programs. If it is, it may have issues with formatting, missing/misplaces bits etc

If you have no luck converting the files, you may be able to recover some of the document by making a copy, changing the extension to `.zip`, and extracting it. You should be able to get the text out of the xml files inside - you may also find a PDF file: [[1]](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/31795/opening-apple-pages-09-docs/) [[2]](http://blog.cleverly.com/permalinks/346.html)

N.B. Ubuntu and other Linux systems often now come with Libreoffice instead of OpenOffice - it is basically the same, for the pro and cons see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/315224/178596).