# Unable to open OpenOffice.org suites

Tags: data-recovery, crash, openoffice.org

I use OpenOffice.org 3.2 and as of yesterday I have been unable to open any OpenOffice.org program. If I try to open any program it proceeds to load after which the loading screen disappears but nothing pops up following that process. However if I try to open a document that I already have saved it again proceeds to load after which leaves me with a message titled “OpenOffice.org Document Recovery” and it says:

> Due to an unexpected error, OpenOffice.org crashed, All the files you were working on will now be saved. The next time OpenOffice.org is launched, your files will be recovered automatically. The following files will be recovered:

[image: screenshot]

After that there is nothing and after launching OpenOffice.org I am still receiving this message. Is there anything that i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reinstallation of OO, if you aren't against:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge openoffice*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then download OO (4.1.1) from here:

http://www.openoffice.org/download/other.html#aoo

Or if you want older version (3.4)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/openoffice 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install apache-openoffice
```

**Or even better, install Libre Office** which is in the repos and will do the same job (but uninstall OO before).

For reference:

[What is the difference between OpenOffice and the newly created LibreOffice?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6706/what-is-the-difference-between-openoffice-and-the-newly-created-libreoffice)